# Subsetting a vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector

Is there an easy way in c++ to extract elements from a vector that have a certain property? The vector contains objects from a class called "Individual" which I defined myself.

I'm looking for something like the c++ equivalent of this command in SQL:

```
> NewVector = SELECT * FROM MyVector WHERE Age > 10
```

or this one in R:

```
> NewVector <- subset(MyVector, Age > 10)
```

So basically, I want to scan through all the elements of `MyVector` and add them to `NewVector` whenever they meet the condition `MyVector[i].Age > 10`.

Here is how these vectors are defined:

```
> vector<Individual> MyVector(20000); // this one later gets filled with stuff

> vector<Individual> NewVector(0); // i want this to be a subset of MyVector
```

Comment: C++ has a bunch of algorithms defined in `<algorithm>`. They are typically defined in a way that they can be combined with custom predicates, in case the builtin ones don't fit your goal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The idiomatic way to do this, I believe, is with `std::copy_if`. You give it the iterators on the list, and an inserter on a new list, and a function object for the predicate.

Something like

```
std::copy_if(MyVector.begin(), MyVector.end(), std::back_inserter(NewVector), [] (Individual i) { return i.Age > 10; });
```

EDIT: Be careful that the copy semantics are what you want. If you've got your `Individual`s in the vector itself, not pointers, then this will cause the `NewVector` to not have the same objects as before, because they're being copied. In general, C++ has no (good) way of filling a vector with objects that are shared with another vector; you might wish to consider `vector<std::shared_ptr<Individual>>` instead.

Comment: Thanks! I realised after posting this that having two separate copies is not much good to me in my current application. You anticipated this issue and now I have two ways of doing it.

Comment: @walter `std::reference_wrapper<T>` in the filter result, or `T*` dumb pointers, can also work,

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the following way

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

//...

vector<Individual> MyVector(20000); // this one later gets filled with stuff
vector<Individual> NewVector; // i want 

//...

auto older_than_10 = []( const Individual &i ) { return i.Age > 10; };

auto n = std::count_if( MyVector.begin(), MyVector.end(), older_than_10 );

NewVector.reserve( n );

std::copy_if( MyVector.begin(), MyVector.end(), 
              std::back_inserter( NewVector ), older_than_10 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class F>
struct filter_t{
  F f;
  template<class T,class A>
  std::vector<T> operator()(std::vector<T,A> const& v)const{
    std::vector<T> r;
    std::copy_if( v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(r), f );
    return r;
  }
};
template<class F,class R=filter_t<std::decay_t<F>>>
R filter(F&&f){return {std::forward<F>(f)};}
```

makes a filter from a lambda.  Use:

```
auto newVec = filter([](int x){return x>10;})( oldVec );
```